# android cache my webServise results

Tags: php, android, web-services, caching, clear-cache

I'am making a game and make a website to store the Score Board when I call the webservise the old  Score Board appears !!! I tried  to open the webServise from the android browser but the browser appears the old  Score Board when i "refresh" android web Browser the new one appears 
how can I Solve this Problem?
this is my app link on the play store I need to update it soon

[My Application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.osamahq.fastfingers&hl=en)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using web Service not WebView
and finally I found the solution

```
 HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://example.com/dir/page.php?"+r.nextInt(1000));
```

putting a random number as a parameter  make the request Different
thanx all

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using a WebView.

It's actually really simple. You should have Googled for "android webview disable cache" and you would see multiple resources...

```
WebView browser = new WebView(this);
WebSettings settings = browser.getSettings();
settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
wv.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(wv), "JSI"); -



  private class JavaScriptInterface {   
 private final WebView m_wv;  
  public JavaScriptInterface(WebView wv)
 {       m_wv = wv;   
 }  
  public void reload() 
{       m_wv.reload();   
} }
```

See more at: http://gurushya.com/customizing-android-webview/#sthash.X87HCv01.dpuf

or other way is:

```
webView.loadUrl( "javascript:window.location.reload( true )" );
```